# Data Plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have two arrays say X and Y with same dimension. I can plot each points (x,y) by `plot(X,Y)`. But how can I color them according to their given labels?

Say X = [3, 4, 2, 5, 6], Y = [2, 2, 1, 5, 6] and label = [1, 2, 2, [1,2], 2]. Here I all have to do is to color points with label=1 with blue and points in label=2 by red. How can I do this?

Comment: check out `scatter()`. Also, what do you mean by `label = [1, 2, 2, [1,2], 2]`, specifically the [1,2] part?

Comment: @Oleg label is a cell array. Here [1,2] means that the point belongs to both of labels.

Comment: Not totally sure I understand the question, but would a hold work? By saying `hold on` you could essentially make different plots in the same screen according to what color you wanted the data to be.

Comment: What's the color for label [1,2] then?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to optimize this code and even get away without using the loop but this should get you started

```
for i=1:length(X)
    xdot=X(i)
    ydot=Y(i)
    Ldot=label(i)
    col=[1 0 0;0 0 1];
    plot(xdot,ydot,'color',col(Ldot,:),'marker','o');
    hold on
end
```